# Why does a random shuffled array repeat

Tags: arrays, swift, shuffle

I shuffle my array.

I then assign a value to each of the indices in the array.

I then perform an action on each indices. In this case turning the colour of a cell in the array red. Despite having assigned a different value to each of the indices in the shuffled array I still get repetition and sometimes the same cell stays red for more than one second in a row. Why is this, it's almost as if the array is being constantly shuffled in between If statements? Code is below.

I have edited the code to show the entire viewController.

```
   import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var theview: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var timerx: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var square1: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square2: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square3: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square4: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square5: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square6: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square7: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square8: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var square9: UIImageView!

    var viewArray = [UIImageView]()

    var timer:Timer?
    var seconds = 11







    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timeElapsed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        }

         @objc func timeElapsed() {
       seconds -= 1
       timerx.text = "\(seconds)"
       if seconds <= 0 {
           timer?.invalidate()
                     }
      viewArray = [square1,square2,square3,square4,square5,square6,square7,square8,square9]

            func allcellsYellow(){
                           square1.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square2.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square3.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square4.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square5.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square6.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square7.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square8.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                           square9.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
                                     }
            func allcellsRed(){
                                      square1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square5.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square6.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square7.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square8.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                      square9.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                                }

            viewArray.shuffle()


            let randomcell = (viewArray[0])
            let randomcell2 = (viewArray[1])
            let randomcell3 = (viewArray[2])
            let randomcell4 = (viewArray[3])
            let randomcell5 = (viewArray[4])
            let randomcell6 = (viewArray[5])
            let randomcell7 = (viewArray[6])
            let randomcell8 = (viewArray[7])
            let randomcell9 = (viewArray[8])


            if seconds == 10 {
                randomcell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 10 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 9 {
                randomcell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 9 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 8 {
                randomcell3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 8 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 7 {
                randomcell4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 7 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 6 {
                randomcell5.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 6 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 5 {
                randomcell6.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 5 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 4 {
                randomcell7.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 4 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 3 {
                randomcell8.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 3 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 2 {
                randomcell9.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 2 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 1 {
                randomcell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            if seconds < 1 {
                allcellsYellow()
            }
            if seconds == 0 {
                allcellsRed()
            }
```

Comment: Uh, please, use arrays. How do you populate the cells? Are the cells reused or not?

Comment: @Sulthan Hi Sulthan. viewArray is already an array. No, the information is all contained on a single screen and does not require reusable cells, the cells in this instance are 9 static imageviews in a grid. I am creating the effect of a flashing red square which moves from cell to cell at random.

Comment: How do you fill `viewArray` before shuffling?

Comment: @PhillipMills I have edited the code in my question to show the entire ViewController. I create an array at top level specifying that the content will be UIImageViews which are connected via IBoutlets to the viewcontroller. I then add this specific views to the array inside the viewdidload.

Comment: BTW google about IBOutletCollection

Comment: thanks @LeoDabus that's incredibly helpful, I have only been learning Swift for 1 week, it's nice to have such constructive input from such a sagacious source.

Comment: Everybody has to start from somewhere. As I said forget about that code and start it all over. My last comment shows you a path to start

Comment: Most of the code you posted is inside the `timeElapsed` function.  If that's what's really in your project, it means the array loading and shuffling is happening every second.

Comment: @LeoDabus Actually, in Swift it's just `IBOutlet` with an array type. Of course, it cannot be `weak`. The thing is that whenever someone uses a couple of variables distinguished only by a numeric suffix, it means that an array should have been used. For example your `func allcellsYellow()` can be implemented using a simple iteration over that array. You actually have an array already there.

Comment: @Sulthan it would be much easier to just have all image views in a single outlet. I don't know whats wrong about my suggestion. `@IBOutlet var squares: [UIImageView]!`

Comment: @LeoDabus I was only telling that there is no `IBOutletCollection` in Swift. The second part of the comment wasn't directed at you.

Comment: @Sulthan I did not say that it was a type just what to google for

Comment: @PhillipMills Thank you for that constructive answer. When I move any of the code outside of the timer function none of it ever fires. The timer runs down but none of the cells change colour. And if i move the timer into the view did load it says obj can only be used with classes.

Comment: @JAC You should never rely on a timer to measure elapsed time. You should store a date and check the time interval since that date. There is no guarantee that the timer method will be called at the right time

Comment: JAC what is your goal? Are you trying to turn every view red in a random order? Or just make each of them red for a second and when the timer finished all of them gets red?

Comment: @LeoDabus I want them to turn red for 1 second, then turn yellow again. Then when the count gets to 0 and they all go red. On the next level up I will increase the speed at which the squares turn red as part of the game I am building in order to learn. But for not I just want to get this basic level to work.

Comment: @JAC check my post. Hope it helps you organizing your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm keeping this code as similar as possible to yours so that you can see what *structure* changes are necessary.  As people have said, there are lots of things you can do to make it more concise and manageable.

Please take this only as a rearrangement suggestion, not as a good solution!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var theview: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var timerx: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var square1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var square9: UIImageView!

var viewArray = [UIImageView]()

var timer:Timer?
var seconds = 11

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timeElapsed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        viewArray = [square1,square2,square3,square4,square5,square6,square7,square8,square9]
        viewArray.shuffle()
    }

    func allcellsYellow(){
        square1.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square2.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square3.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square4.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square5.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square6.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square7.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square8.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
        square9.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow
    }
    func allcellsRed(){
        square1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square5.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square6.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square7.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square8.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        square9.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    fileprivate func updateColours() {
        let randomcell = (viewArray[0])
        let randomcell2 = (viewArray[1])
        let randomcell3 = (viewArray[2])
        let randomcell4 = (viewArray[3])
        let randomcell5 = (viewArray[4])
        let randomcell6 = (viewArray[5])
        let randomcell7 = (viewArray[6])
        let randomcell8 = (viewArray[7])
        let randomcell9 = (viewArray[8])


        if seconds == 10 {
            randomcell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 10 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 9 {
            randomcell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 9 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 8 {
            randomcell3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 8 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 7 {
            randomcell4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 7 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 6 {
            randomcell5.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 6 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 5 {
            randomcell6.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 5 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 4 {
            randomcell7.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 4 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 3 {
            randomcell8.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 3 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 2 {
            randomcell9.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 2 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 1 {
            randomcell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if seconds < 1 {
            allcellsYellow()
        }
        if seconds == 0 {
            allcellsRed()
        }
    }

    @objc func timeElapsed() {
       seconds -= 1
       timerx.text = "\(seconds)"
        print("\(seconds)")
       if seconds <= 0 {
           timer?.invalidate()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateColours()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfectly. I can assure you that as a part of the learning experience I am going to be tidying up my code, making it more efficient and presentable, but for now I was stuck on this basic functionality element. I will study this closely. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need one outlet for each image view. You can connect all of them to a single IBOutlet collection. Then you can simply create a collection of its indices and shuffle it. You can also finish cleaning most of your code creating a method to turn all your backgrounds or just a single one to a specific color:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var squares: [UIImageView]!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    var timer = Timer()
    var indices: [Int] = []
    var seconds = 11
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = .scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timeElapsed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        indices = squares.indices.shuffled()
        setAllSquares(to: .systemYellow)
    }
    func setAllSquares(to color: UIColor) {
        squares.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = color }
    }
    func setSquare(at index: Int, to color: UIColor) {
        squares[index].backgroundColor = color
    }
    @objc func timeElapsed(_ timer: Timer) {
        timeLabel.text = "seconds: \(seconds)"
        if seconds <= 0 { timer.invalidate() }
        switch seconds {
        case 2 ... 10:
            setAllSquares(to: .systemYellow)
            setSquare(at: indices[seconds-2], to: .systemRed)
        case 1:
            setAllSquares(to: .systemYellow)
        case 0:
            setAllSquares(to: .systemRed)
        default:
            break
        }
        seconds -= 1
    }
}
```

---

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv9etic2x9ektcm/Swuares.zip?dl=1)

Comment: Thank you very much Leo. My faith in this community is affirmed today. I appreciate your time. This code worked great. Thank you for your time. I am honoured. Goodnight. I have learned much today.